# Why is this an array out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

Why does this cause an array out of bounds exception ?

```
 x[10][2] = 5;
```

Should this be assigning the 3rd spot of the 11th array, the value 5

I thought of it in a rectangular way.
Its like we have to count 11 rows(representing the 10 arrays)
and then we have to go to the 3rd column that is the 2

OR

I should be looking at it as an array looking for the 11th spot in an array of size 2 that doesn't actually exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Why does this cause an array out of bounds exception?

```
 x[10][2] = 5;
```

This only happens when you try to access a position out of the range that you had defined for your array. For example

```
int x[20][20];
```

You can make  x[10][2] = 5; without a problem because 10 < 20 and 2 < 20. But if you did:

```
x[30][20] = 5;
```

You would have the out of bounds exception because you are trying to access the position (30,20) of the 2D array, a position that surpasses the size of the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 11th element of **x** an array? If it is, what is its length? 
 You are receiving that error because it's likely the length of that element is less than 3.
Test it by trying

```
 
  System.out.printf(x[10].length);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `x[10][2]` does not exist.

It can be either because `x[10]` is not a valid element (i.e. `x.length` is equal to or greater than 10), or `x[10][2]` is not a valid element (i.e. `x[10].length` is equal to or greater than 2). The exception message tells you which index fails, if they differ.

Note that a multidimensional array doesn't have to be a matrix. This is called a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

For example, consider the following code (from Wikipedia):

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][]; // creates 2 rows
arr[0] = new int[3]; // 3 columns for row 0
arr[1] = new int[5]; // create 5 columns for row 1
```

Referencing `arr[0][4]` would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, while referencing `arr[1][4]` would not.

---

*As Mark Stevens already mentioned in the comments, which one is the row and which one the column, is subjective. As opposed to what jazzbassrob says in the comments, Java has neither row-major nor column-major order. In fact, in Java, there is no such thing as a two-dimensional array, instead, it's actually an array of arrays.*